# Transform JSON query filter into SQL?

Tags: java, sql, json

I'm looking for a `java` library that can translate `json` input into `SQL` dynamically.

For example, the library could expect the following json data:

```
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "field": "firstname",
            "value": [
                "John",
                "Doe"
            ],
            "operator": "in"
        },
        {
            "rules": [
                {
                    "field": "age",
                    "value": 18,
                    "operator": "EQUALS"
                }
            ],
            "condition": "AND"
        }
    ]
}
```

And should then be able of translating this into a dynamic sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM persons where firstname IN ("John", "Doe") AND age = 18;
```

Is there any existing framework that I could build this upon?

Comment: It’s not exactly what you want, but maybe somehow you’d be able to bend your requirements? Anyway, I created this library: https://github.com/mmalek06/JsonSql . Maybe instead of creating filters like you do, you could directly create sql queries?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about library to get the expected output. But you can use the following code to write Java method.

Assuming that input will be JSON object.

```
    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj; 

    // getting fieldname and operator
    String field= (String) jo.get("field"); 
    String operator= (String) jo.get("operator"); 
    //getting values
    JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) jo.get("value"); 

    // iterating values
    Iterator itr2 = ja.iterator();
```

Then you can use above to write dynamic SQL query.

Comment: Yes but I'd have to implement the specific sql syntax for parsing. I hoped there could be a library so I'd not have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You can check this url: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-convert-JSON-to-an-SQL-Query